# Perl system calls when running as another user using sudo

Tags: linux, perl, redhat

I have developed a perl script which provides a menu driven functionality to allow users to carry out some simple tasks.

I need the users to be able to carry out tasks such as copying files (keeping the current date and permissions), running other programs (such as less or vi) as a different user. The script uses alot of use of the system() function. I want the users to start the menu by calling:

```
sudo -u perluser /usr/bin/perl /data/perlscripts/scripta.pl
```

This should start the script as perl user, which it does, and then carry out different tasks depending on what the user selects. The problem is that whenever I use a system call such as

```
system("clear");
```

I get the following error

```
Can't exec "clear": Permission denied at /data/perlscripts/scripta.pl line 3
```

If I run the script by logging in as perluser then it all runs succesfully.

Is there any way to get this working? I do not want users to be able to log in as perluser as I need to control what they are able to run. I also do not want to run a command like

```
system("sudo -u perluser clear");
```

as I would then require a different team to set up all the sudo commands I wanted to run (which they will probably refuse to do) and this would not be scalable if I have to add extra commands at somepoint.

Thanks,

Comment: do you need to add sudo commands to the script itself instead? IE `system("sudo -u peluser /bin/to/clear")`

Comment: This is what I do not want to do, by doing this I put extra resource requirement on the linux admins to set up all the different sudo commands that would be required and they are unlikely to want to do this and would also make changes longer to implement as I requirested this work to be completed each time.

Comment: Hard to tell what's on line 3 actually! Please show a minimum (non-)working example, allowing us to reproduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you probably need to add the `-i` option ("simulate initial login") to `sudo`:

```
sudo -i -u perluser /usr/bin/perl /data/perlscripts/scripta.pl
```

That will ensure that `.profile` or `.login` or whatnot is run properly, and therefore that `$PATH` is set up properly and so on. It will really be, in almost all respects, as if `perluser` were actually logging in and running `/usr/bin/perl /data/perlscripts/scripta.pl` at the shell.

Comment: While I agree that this is one solution, if you are running a `sudo` version < 1.7 you will encounter "cannot execute binary file" errors.

Comment: Thank, this resolved the issue. For anyone else with the same issue, another solution I have found is that my Linux Admin had added the noexec arguement when setting up my sudo access meaning it would not allow me to exec other commands, removing this has allowed me to do what I need using my original command `sudo -u perluser /usr/bin/perl /data/perlscripts/scripta.pl`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a slightly different approach, but couldn't you set `perluser`'s shell to `/data/perlscripts/scripta.pl`?  This would avoid the headaches usually associated with `sudo` configuration if you have multiple machines.  The end user would simply use `login perluser` instead of `sudo`.  When you script exits, the login session will go away.  No need to provide any more of a jail than this right?

**Alternate (and maybe correct) Answer**

I think that the root of the problem is that Perl's `exec` *does not* use a shell in most cases.  This means that `"clear"` is meaningless since the shell is what implements searching through `$PATH` to find the command.  Here is the relevant [`perldoc` from `system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  Note the emphasis.

> o **system** LIST
>
> o **system PROGRAM LIST**
>
> Does exactly the same thing as <kbd>exec LIST</kbd>, except that a fork is done first and the parent process waits for the child process to exit. Note that argument processing varies depending on the number of arguments. If there is more than one argument in `LIST`, or if `LIST` is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the rest of the list. *If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).* **If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to <kbd>execvp</kbd> , which is more efficient.**

Try changing `system("clear")` to either `system("/usr/bin/clear")` or `system("clear;")`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I see with this solution is that I still require to log on as perluser to run other tasks so would need to keep my bash shell access.

Comment: The question unanswered is *why* the perl script cannot run with the calling user's UID. Usually such "solutions" are security nightmares unless done correctly.